# which plugin i want to dowlod for develop Android and Windows Phone apps

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I have a VS2010 and VS2012 Professional in my PC I'm using a os window 7 and this both VS installed here I want to develop Android  and Windows phone apps i want to know which pluging i have to instal to start learning to develop Android  and Windows phone apps on my system. please let me know how can i start working on to to learn development of Android  and Windows phone apps.

Answer (score 2):

For develop in android you can use Eclipse IDE and install the plugin. See this: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

For the windows phone you can continue using visual studio. Download windows phone 8 sdk here: http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Answer (score 0):

Developping on android or windows phone requires different langages. To develop on android, you'll need to learn [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), but for Windows, you can create app using C#. You'll also need to download their SDK from windows dev website.

But if you're a true beginner, the best advice I can give you is, if you really want to developp mobile app, starting by web app. You can create one web app in one langage that will work on every smartphone, using javascript or any web langage.

You can also find some really powerfull framework like [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop for both, Windows Phone and Android using Visual Studio and C# have a look at [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/).

It allows to write Android and iOS apps using C# too. A good design of the app, separating platform specific code, will allow you to share a great amount of code between different platforms.